# String.Replace not replacing

Tags: c#

I'm doing some file clean up in an xml file and trying to use string.Replace to replace certain text blocks but it does not seem to be replacing the text that I am searching on.

My clean up code is follows

```
private Stream PrepareFile(string path)
{
    string data = File.ReadAllText(path);

    var newData = data.Replace("<a:FMax xmlns:b=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" i:type=\"b:string\"/>", "<a:FMax>0</a:FMax>")
        .Replace("<a:KVy xmlns:b=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" i:type=\"b:string\"/>", "<a:KVy>0</a:KVy>")
        .Replace("<a:Td xmlns:b=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" i:type=\"b:string\"/>", "<a:Td>0</a:Td>")
        .Replace("<a:VyLim xmlns:b=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" i:type=\"b:string\"/>", "<a:VyLim>0</a:VyLim>");

    var newData2 = newData.Replace("<a:VxTableSxI3_2I xmlns:b=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" i:type=\"b:string\"/>", "<a:VxTableSxI3_2I>0</a:VxTableSxI3_2I>");

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(newData2);
    return new MemoryStream(bytes);
}
```

I should be able to write back to the original 'data' variable, but I split the variables out to be able to compare the strings before and after the replace.  My xml file contains the following values(copied verbatim)

```
<a:LongitudinalTracker z:Id="i58">
    <Name xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HmsSim.EntityModule.BaseTypes" i:nil="true"/>
    <a:FMax xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="b:string"/>
    <a:K>2</a:K>
    <a:KVy xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="b:string"/>
    <a:Td xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="b:string"/>
    <a:VyLim xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="b:string"/>
</a:LongitudinalTracker>
```

And the before and after strings look identical.  I'm sure I am missing something silly, but I can't see what it is.  Most of the answers to similar questions point out that the original code is not using the return value, but in this case I am definitely using the return value.

Comment: Most likely the strings are not actually contained in the source. Could easily be an escape error.. - Write a test for this..!

Comment: Hint: use the `@` in front of your strings to avoid escaping everything so that it's easier to read

Comment: Assuming the text is valid XML to start with, I'd strongly advise you to use XML libraries (e.g. LINQ to XML) to manipulate it rather than direct string replacement operations, which will be really brittle.

Comment: Since your xml is invalid I suspect you anonimized your real data. And doing that in question like this making it useless.

Comment: The symbol that needs escaping is the " in the strings themselves.  I don't believe the @ symbol will automatically escape those correctly.  Though it is possible I'm not using it correctly.

Comment: `newData` and `newData2` are the same because the search string is not contained (at least in your example).

Comment: @Evk the xml above is a copied and pasted section of a much much larger file.  Some lines were deleted but no data was changed.

Comment: @Fildor you are correct, I would expect newData and newData2 to be the same....but the problem is newData and Data are identical as well.

Comment: data and newData differed as expected when I tried: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Smfkmo

Comment: Assuming this is your REAL data and your REAL code, then it's working as you expect. Have you set a breakpoint and looked at newData2?

Comment: But even though my little test worked: I second @JonSkeet's suggestion. Strongly ...

Comment: A case for Xsl transform imho.

Comment: @JonSkeet I attempted to use an XMLReader it became really upset about the : in the names.  Hence why I went with an admittedly brute force string.replace method.

Comment: MSDN: To include a double quotation mark in an @-quoted string, double it. - Also: If you want to go with Replace at the very least assign those strings to variables, so you can properly work with them!

Comment: It should be fine so long as those namespace aliases are declared somewhere. It's hard to know without a short but complete example file though. (I would personally go straight to parsing with XDocument.Parse unless you really *need* to use XmlReader.)

Comment: @Fildor Your test definitely works in the fiddle....but I it's definitely not working for my file and I'm struggling to see why.  I've even changed my search strings to be escaped.

Comment: I do see that. Actually I hoped it would fail, too, so I can see where the error is. Now what have we learned? Either you are "looking" wrong ... but I guess you double and tripple checked that you are looking at the correct strings or ... hm. Genuinly clueless at the moment.

Comment: If it's working in the fiddle with the data that you posted, then nobody will be able to help you here. You'll have to post your actual file so we can check it. You can delete everything except the section in your question and try it. If it still doesn't work, post that minimal file (the file itself, not a copy of the data) so we can download it and check it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm trying to setup a LINQ to XML, I have var xml = XDocument.Parse(data); which works, but when I try var longTracker = from item in xml.Descendants("a:LongitudinalTracker") select item; I get an exception of The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

Comment: @RacilHilan That's completely fair, I will get to work on that as well.

Comment: @PlTaylor: Yes, that's because that's not how you address namespaces in LINQ to XML. There are *lots* of questions about LINQ to XML on Stack Overflow and tutorials though.

Comment: Well, this turned into an XY problem. It sounds like your actual problem is querying using namespaces. Does this code work for you:

`XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";

 var longTracker = from item in xml.Descendants(ns + "LongitudinalTracker") select item;`

Comment: @JonSkeet Your suggestion worked, and is obviously a lot more robust.  Thanks for leading me down that path, I appreciate it.  I'm open to doing what ever we should with this question, I'm not sure how it can help the community other than as a cautionary tale.

Comment: Well, you could add an answer showing how you actually addressed the problem, or you could delete the question. Either of these work for me.

Comment: The real question can't be reproduced so it is due to a typo; best delete it..

Answer (score 0):

As suggested I am posting the code that ended up solving this.

```
private Stream PrepareFile(string path)
{
    string data = File.ReadAllText(path);

    var xml = XDocument.Parse(data);

    XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/HmsSim.EntityModule.Entities.SimulationEntities.Track";
    var longTracker = from item in xml.Descendants(ns + "LongitudinalTracker") select item;

    foreach (var xElement in longTracker.Elements())
    {
        XNamespace nsI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        if (xElement.Attribute(nsI + "type") != null)
        {
            xElement.Attribute(nsI + "type").Remove();
            XAttribute attribute = new XAttribute(nsI + "nil", "true");
            xElement.Add(attribute);
        }
    }

    var latTracker = from item in xml.Descendants(ns + "LateralTracker") select item;

    foreach (var xElement in latTracker.Elements())
    {
        XNamespace nsI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        if (xElement.Attribute(nsI + "type") != null)
        {
            xElement.Attribute(nsI + "type").Remove();
            XAttribute attribute = new XAttribute(nsI + "nil", "true");
            xElement.Add(attribute);
        }
    }

    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
    xml.Save(stream);
    // Rewind the stream ready to read from it elsewhere
    stream.Position = 0;

    return stream;
}
```

This code works and is less brittle than the original code.  As always, suggestions are welcome.  Thanks to everyone who commented and led me towards this answer, I appreciate it.